# How to add toolbar and pager to new.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, new-products

How to add toolbar and pager to new.phtml ? I tried this code below but the toolbar/pager doesn't show up. Thankyou!!

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/product-custom-list.js</name>
    </action>
    <action ifconfig="spp/setting/enableModule" method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/simple_product_pricing_quickview.js</name>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/category-layered.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content"> 
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="just.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"> 
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/> 
        </block>
        <action method="setCategoryId">
            <category_id>2</category_id>
        </action> 
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name </action> 
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
    </block>
</reference> 
<reference name="left"> 
    <block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view" name="amshopby.navleft" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> 
</reference>
<cms_page_view>
    <update handle="infinitescroll"/>
</cms_page_view>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="infinitescroll/init" name="infinitescroll_init">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>strategery/infinitescroll/init_notoolbar.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this one :

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Then go to your new.phtml and add this code where you want to display the toolbar :

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('product_list_toolbar'); ?>
```

Clear your Magento and browser cache.